# Git author is set globally, but the default is still used at commit time

Tags: git

I have set git's global author.

```
git config --global user.name "StudentWeis"
git config --global user.email "studentweis@gmail.com"
```

But when I commited, the default is still used.

```
$ git config -l

user.name=StudentWeis
user.email=studentweis@gmail.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@gitee.com:studentwei/wei-config.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


$ sudo git commit -am test
[master 356004c] test
 Committer: root <root@y24vb738db0tgjg.ECD.ACS>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
your configuration file:

    git config --global --edit

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author
```

I searched the Internet for a long time but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: does the same happen in a new (clean) repository?

Comment: Global configuration is *per user*, to be applied across all repositories. You are running `git` as a *different* user. I'm not sure why you would do that, but you are perhaps looking for *system* configuration (via the `--system` option).

Comment: There seems to be little reason for a Git repository to require root access. If it needs special access privileges, a specific user should be created for that purpose rather than just dumping it under root.

Comment: @lucidbrot Yes, I built a new repository and tested it, and the same results.

Comment: @chepner Oh I see! Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 1):

Global configuration options only apply to the current user. You are running `git` as root, so your global configuration is not used; root's configuration is.

If you really want an option to be set for *all* users, use `--system` instead. But `user.name` does not seem like an option that should be set for all users. Rather, you should probably have a specific system user created to provide access to this repository (*not* `root`), and run `git config --global` for *that* user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I mistakenly thought that global meant all users.